# Angular2 Atualizar variáveis entre componentes

Tags: angularjs-directives, angular

Estou iniciando no **angular 2** e gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de fazer o seguinte:
Tenho 2 components, toolbar.component e profile.component.

Quando o usuário atualizar o nome do logo e sua foto (isso já funciona) preciso atualizar isso no toolbar (que hoje exibe informação estática)

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso ? Queria que as variáveis estivessem disponíveis para toda aplicação pois no toolbar vai ter uma logica de mensagens baseadas no perfil do usuario, dependendo de que informações ainda faltam preencher por exemplo.

toolbar.component.html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['']" id="logo-container" class="brand-logo" >Logo xxxx</a>
<li  *ngIf="tokenAuthService.userSignedIn()">
      <a [routerLink]="['/perfil']" class="nav-picture" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(http://res.cloudinary.com/dgekdykfj/image/upload/v1492383265/x7qow7ayvvhyojw7d1mi.jpg)'}"></a>
</li>
```

Não sei quais arquivos mais seriam necessários para analisar, por isso não coloquei todos aqui. Obrigado

Comment: To com uma dúvida similar, alguma novidade por ai?